# matplotlib: box plot for each category

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

My pandas data frame has two columns: `category` and `duration`. And 
I use the following code to make a box plot of all data points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.boxplot(df.duration)
plt.show()
```

However, if I want one box fore each `category`, how do I modify the above code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it with pandas

```
#df=pd.DataFrame({'category':list('aacde'),'duration':[1,3,2,3,4]}) sample data
df.assign(index=df.groupby('category').cumcount()).pivot('index','category','duration').plot(kind='box')
```

[image]

Comment: How do I add outliers in this pandas version ? If not, how do we do it in matplotlib?

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [Wen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712368/1356000), which is spot on, you might want to check out [the seaborn library](https://seaborn.pydata.org/). It was made to do this kind of plot.

> Seaborn is a Python visualization library based on matplotlib. It
>   provides a high-level interface for drawing attractive statistical
>   graphics.

Check the [documentation for boxplots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot)

> Draw a box plot to show distributions with respect to categories.

```
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='category', y='duration')
```

[image]