# Matplotlib boxplot with one box for each category or value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I have one csv like this one (separator is `;`)

```
Day;col_1;col_2;col_3;month
20180101;652;0;25803;1
20180102;737;6;25677;1
20180103;653;10;27955;1
20180104;914;10;27722;1
[a lot of rows]
20181228;924;35;30191;12
20181229;721;18;28601;12
20181230;902;17;28098;12
20181231;778;30;28909;12
```

I would like to plot in separate axis, the values of columns `col_1`, `col_2` and `col_3`.
In each axis I would like to have one different box for each month

I know this is the way to do it in seaborn for just one column, but I would like to do it using `pandas` an `matplotlib` only:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='month', y='col1')
```

[image: result_with_seaborn]

After checking it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712368/4919040), I have found that this may be quite approximate to what I want:

```
df.assign(index=df.groupby('month').cumcount()).pivot('index','month','col1').plot(kind='box')
```

[image: matplotlib try]

Is there any more efficient approach?

How to add in the same plot, several axes (meaning subplots) for each `colX` ?

Comment: `df.assign(...).pivot(...).plot.box(subplots=True)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider matplotlib [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and elementwise with each column, iteratively pass axes into `ax` of seaborn's [`boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) for each numeric y column.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12,4))

for i, col in enumerate(["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]):
   sns.boxplot(data=df, x='month', y=col, ax=ax[i])
   ax[i].set_title(col.title())

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

To demonstrate with random data

```
np.random.seed(1142019)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'),
                   'col_1': np.random.randint(1, 10, 365),
                   'col_2': np.random.randint(10, 100, 365),
                   'col_3': np.random.randint(2500, 29999, 365)
                  })

df['month'] = df['Day'].dt.month
```

Above code, generates this plot

[image: Box SubPlot Output]