# Boxplot for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataset that looks kind of like this (with made up examples):

| text | sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| i need more power | negative |
| wheres your motivation | positive |
| this place was my fathers home | negative |
| in my restless dreams, I see that town | positive |

I wanted to use matplotlib's or seaborn's box plots to see how many texts are negative, positive, and neutral, so I can see the distributions and if there are outliers, etc.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to do it with strings instead of numbers. I tried using df.replace() to turn the negative, positive and neutral strings to -1, 1 and 0 respectively but that seems like overkill and really bad practice. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib: box plot for each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712274/matplotlib-box-plot-for-each-category)

Comment: I tried this before and could not plot anything as I needed at least one numerical value, of which neither text not sentiment is, hence my problem